# How can I get Closure Compiler to report all warnings?

Tags: warnings, compiler-warnings, google-closure-compiler

Closure Compiler documentation says "But even --warning_level=VERBOSE doesn't give you all the warnings that Closure Compiler can emit". I want them all, and for that matter, I would like --jscomp_error= to report an error for any warning.

I am not exactly sure from the documentation on https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings what I am supposed to do. Do I include multiple --jscomp's for every type listed, or is there a short-cut that ensures I have not missed anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either:

- Specify `--jscomp_error` flags for each type. The list is displayed when you run the compiler with the `--help` flag.
- Make a custom build of the compiler.